# Weights, Representations and Tensors

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, tensors, dynkin-diagrams

I am trying to learn about Lie Theory and I am trying to solve some problems from various lectures notes I have found online. But I have completely stuck on this question:

> We work with $A_2=\mathfrak{sl}(3)$. Let's denote an irred by the Dynkin labels of its highest weight. Then $\textbf{3}=(10)$ and $\bar{\textbf{3}}=(01)$. Show by using tensors that $\textbf{3}\otimes{\textbf{3}}$ contains two irred of which $(01)$ is one of them.
> Draw a picture of the weights in the other one, using the additivity of weights in a tensor product. What is its highest weight? Is it always true, that the tensor product of a representation with itself, with the highest weight $\lambda$, contains the rep with the highest weight $2\lambda$?

My attempt is the follow:

First I thought that I could use Young tableaux so $$ {\textbf{3}}\otimes{\textbf{3}}= (10)\otimes(10) = \square \otimes \square = \square\square\oplus\stackrel{\square}{\square}=(20)\otimes(01) $$
But then I thought that it says "with tensors", so it maybe not the wanted solution.
So I thought maybe it wants me to write: $$\psi_a\otimes\psi_b = \frac{1}{2}(\psi_{(a}\psi_{b)}+\psi_{[a}\psi_{b]})$$

Then it asks for the picture of the weights(I don't really understand which picture it wants me to draw). So I draw the weight space diagram(which I found in some other more advanced note)

[[image: For the <span class=]$(11)$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43VCi.jpg)

[[image: For the <span class=]$(01)$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Dn10.jpg)

And as it asks for the $(11)$, we see using the weight space diagram(and its rules) that the highest weight is in the center and it is $2$.

So for the final question, I can then again draw the weight space diagram and conclude that **yes**, the tensor product of a rep with highest weight $\lambda$ with itself contains the representation with $2\lambda$ highest weight (and it will lie in the center).

That is what I have done until now, I hope that something makes sense or is not entirely wrong! Any help and hints would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: We have $3\otimes\overline{3} = 8\oplus 1$, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3944989/decomposing-representation-of-sl3-mathbbc-into-direct-sum-of-irreducibles?rq=1). Here $8$ is the adjoint representation of dimension $8$ and $1$ is the trivial $1$-dimesnional representation. And we have $3\otimes 3=6\oplus \overline{3}$. One could write this as $L(\omega_1)\otimes L(\omega_1)=L(2\omega_1)\oplus L(\omega_{\ell})$ for type $A_{\ell}$ with $\ell=2$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde What is $L(\omega)$ and why we can write such a relation?

Comment: $L(\omega_i)$ is the irreducible highest weight module with fundamental weight $\omega_i$. For type $A_n$, so for $\mathfrak{sl}(n+1)$, the natural representation of dimension $n+1$ is $L(\omega_1)$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde How can I prove this thought? Thank you for your time :)

Comment: It is proved in, say, Fulton Harris book on "Representation Theory".

Comment: Where it says "using tensors" I imagine it means split the tensor product into symmetric and alternating tensors. The first forms a 6 dimensional rep and the second is the 3 dimensional dual rep that you are looking for (you'll have to verify that by its weights).